# Clear left creates a gap in firefox/chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm getting pretty rusty in html/css and I introduced a problem in my web application when I created a new control on the left side.

```
<div id="leftnav">
<ul><li class="saveAndExit"><a class="noflag" href="" onclick="">Save and Exit</a></li></ul>
<span id=""><ul><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="btn0','')" onclick="javascript:keepDirtyFlag();undefined">Introduction</a></li></div><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="">Applicant Details</a></li></div><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href=")" onclick="javascript:keepDirtyFlag();undefined">Applicant Details</a></li></div><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="j">Applicant details – Trust</a></li></div><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="javascript:keepDirtyFlag();undefined">Applicant contact person – Trust</a></li></div><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="">Applicant Trustees</a><a onclick="" class="noflag arrow"></a><ul style="display:none"><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="javascript:keepDirtyFlag();undefined">Record 1</a></li><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="">Record 2</a></li></ul></li></div><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="">Eligibility Details</a></li></div><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="">Eligibility Details</a></li></div><div><li><a id="" class="noflag" href="" onclick="">Review</a></li></div></ul></span>
</div>
```

The problem is, that I have a fieldset with fields inside with the following template

```
<div class="field-container"><div class="field-label"><label for="_Name_txt" id="mCtrl0_Name_txt_fieldLabel" accesskey="M">Na<u>m</u>e<span class="field-asterisk"><acronym title="Required">*</acronym></span></label><em></em></div><div class="field-control"><div class="field-wrapper-passive"><input name="ormCtrl0$Name_txt" type="text" id="mCtrl0_Name_txt" dtext="" class="field-text-idle"></div><div class="field-error-passive"><span id="mCtrl0_ctl06" style="color:Red;display:none;">A name is required</span><span id="mCtrl0_ctl07" style="color:Red;display:none;">The Name must not exceed 200 characters</span></div></div><div class="field-clear"></div></div>
```

Which were displayed correctly since the I added the new leftnav control but now, the "field-clear" class

```
 .field-clear {
 clear: left;
 line-height: 1px;
 font-size: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 }
```

clears the navigation list on the left side and creates a huge gap between the first field and the other fields inside my form. How can I solve this?

EDIT : JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/vS8jt/2/embedded/result/

Comment: Please provide a simplified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/vS8jt/2/embedded/result/ , this is not very simplified. All this stuff is embedded inside sharepoint and it's linked very tight together but you can cleary see the gap between the fields there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by floating the main container and then adding a new div that clears it at the bottom of the page.